# Why I can't run Spring app when seperated Main Class and Non-Main Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, class

I'm trying to find a way to test the multiple Spring Apps in the same project. But I have trouble with `Main class` and `Main method`

Below is my simple restAPI.class which creates a web API that accepts POST method:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class restAPITest {

    @PostMapping("/example")
    public String handleExampleRequest(@RequestBody String requestData) {
        // Process the incoming data
        System.out.println("Received data: " + requestData);

        // Return a response
        return "Data received successfully";
    }
}
```

Then I create a `main class` with `main method` to run Spring App, like a normal java app

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(restAPITest.class, args);
    }
}
```

But then I got an error like below

```
Description:

Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.

Action:

Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type
```

Below is my project Structure (Just care about 2 file that I highlight)
[image: structured]

If I put the `main method` inside `public class restAPITest`, it will work like normal. But when separating the `main class`/`main method` like this it won't work. I don't understand why in Spring boot `main method` can't be separated?

Basically, I want my `main class` like below. When I want to test an App, I will comment out other App (I only want to test App by App, not run 3 Spring Apps at the same time). I tried to create 3 classes with 3 main methods inside, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(testSpringApp1.class, args);
        SpringApplication.run(testSpringApp2.class, args);
        //SpringApplication.run(testSpringApp3.class, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `SpringApplication.run(restAPITest.class, args)`, but `restAPITest` is not the Spring Boot Application. `mainClass` is, because that's the one with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. That annotation defines all the component scanning etc.

Normally I would say, use `SpringApplication.run(mainClass.class, args)`, but that will load all the test applications / classes. Instead, annotate each of the test classes with `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })`.